# Why is my WebRTC only working over my local network

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So I am setting up WebRTC for the first time and got it working fine on my local network, but when I tried over another network it just stopped working. I have setup a stun server and a turn server but it's still not working.

This is my configuration, not sure if there could be other factors or other bits of code I should show but this is what I set:

```
const iceConfiguration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
    },
    {
      urls: 'turn:relay1.expressturn.com:3478',
      username: '', // There is a username and password here i just removed it
      credential: ''
    }
  ]
}

const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
```

Comment: do you get any useful info in the browser developer tools?

Comment: There are no messages, but after about 30 seconds, this appears when logging the peerConnection variable:
connectionState: "failed", it gets stuck on connecting, then changes to failed, on local it says success. But nothing that is to useful really